# duplicate href in linkbutton

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using a `LinkButton` inside a `repeater` and i am setting `href` attribute from code behind, but in browser when I view page source, there are two `href` genarated as shown below.

```html
<li id="HeaderMenu_repeaterLevel1Menu_mainMenuLi_0" >
    <a id="HeaderMenu_repeaterLevel1Menu_linkButtonMenu_0"
       href="/Home" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$HeaderMenu$repeaterLevel1Menu$ctl00$linkButtonMenu&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Home</a>
</li>
```

below is my code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkButtonMenu" runat="server"
  CommandName="<%# ((BusinessObjects.Pages.Menu)Container.DataItem).ID %>"
  href="<%# ((BusinessObjects.Pages.Menu)Container.DataItem).URL %>">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I found this issue while checking for w3c errors. How to remove the `href="javascript:__doPostBack...`

I appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: have you set up a href in the controls properties?

Comment: can you point out where its generating double? I mean could you show the code of your generator?

Comment: So, you're setting it in the properties and in the code-behind?

Answer (score 2):

Use `HyperLink` instead of `LinkButton`.

From MSDN:

> Use the LinkButton control to create a hyperlink-style button on the
>   Web page. The LinkButton control has the same appearance as a
>   HyperLink control, but has the same functionality as a Button control.
>   If you want to link to another Web page when the control is clicked,
>   consider using the HyperLink control.

link button is used to post back to the page, not to redirect to other one.

Comment: Thanks.. But Is there any other way with out replacing linkbutton ..  I have used link button in many controls ...

Comment: There probably is, but that would be using control to do something that it was not designed for, so IMO it is better to fix it now and do it properly than hacking it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a contradiction when you set the href yourself AND use a command name ASP.Net handles (it's like you can't decide who's in charge).

So you should not set "href" yourself, you should set the PostBackUrl property instead.

Or use a HyperLink if it suits better your needs.